# How to copy file from PC to Server using File.Copy in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to copy an image file from one machine to another machine, but I'm getting an error that the username and password are incorrect.

I've put my code below:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            dlg.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            dlg.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                string filepath = dlg.FileName;
                // File.Copy(filepath, @"\\172.18.2.33\c$\Mediinfotec" + dlg.SafeFileName, true);

                IntPtr tokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);
                tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

                bool returnValue = LogonUser(@"prime\mediinfo", "prime", "medi@111", 9, 0, ref tokenHandle);

                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.UnauthenticatedPrincipal);
                WindowsIdentity wid = new WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle);
                WindowsImpersonationContext context = wid.Impersonate();

                File.Copy(filepath, @"\\172.18.2.33\c$\Mediinfotec\" + dlg.SafeFileName);

                context.Undo();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are sure the password is correct?

Comment: Yes.But i am sending correct user name and password

Comment: You spoke to your network admin, and they agreed?

Comment: Why are you trying to impersonate a user at all? Every program runs under the end user's account so the server already knows who's trying to copy the file. Instead of *weakening* security by impersonating, just add the user to the group of users that have permission to copy to that file

Comment: @samyrajr what you try to do is something your admins will *hate*. You're weakening security for no reason. It will stop working too, as soon as that password changes.

Comment: @samyrajr the only scenario where impersonation with a fixed password is required is a misconfigured Samba server on a Linux. A well-configures Samba server would communicate with the Active Directory domain controller and use AD security groups instead of hard-coded passwords

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your server *requires* you to connect with a username and password, you can use [`WNetUseConnection` from `mpr.dll`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr.WNetUseConnection) to establish the connection, then [`WNetCancelConnection`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr.WNetCancelConnection) to disconnect when you're done.

I have used this in the past to connect to SMB shares for data collection and so on and it works fine:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Util
{
    public class ConnectSMB : IDisposable
    {
        public string URI { get; private set; }
        public bool Connected { get; private set; } = false;

        public ConnectSMB(string uri, string username, string password)
        {
            string connResult = Native.ConnectToRemote(uri, username, password);

            if (connResult != null)
            {
                URI = $"FAILED: {connResult}";
                Connected = false;
            }
            else
            {
                URI = uri;
                Connected = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Close();
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            if (Connected)
            {
                var disconResult = Native.DisconnectRemote(URI);
                URI = disconResult;
                Connected = false;
            }
        }

        public class Native
        {
            #region Consts
            const int RESOURCETYPE_DISK = 1;
            const int CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE = 0x00000001;
            #endregion

            #region Errors
            public enum ENetUseError
            {
                NoError = 0,
                AccessDenied = 5,
                AlreadyAssigned = 85,
                BadDevice = 1200,
                BadNetName = 67,
                BadProvider = 1204,
                Cancelled = 1223,
                ExtendedError = 1208,
                InvalidAddress = 487,
                InvalidParameter = 87,
                InvalidPassword = 1216,
                MoreData = 234,
                NoMoreItems = 259,
                NoNetOrBadPath = 1203,
                NoNetwork = 1222,
                BadProfile = 1206,
                CannotOpenProfile = 1205,
                DeviceInUse = 2404,
                NotConnected = 2250,
                OpenFiles = 2401
            }
            #endregion

            #region API methods
            [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
            private static extern ENetUseError WNetUseConnection(
                IntPtr hwndOwner,
                NETRESOURCE lpNetResource,
                string lpPassword,
                string lpUserID,
                int dwFlags,
                string lpAccessName,
                string lpBufferSize,
                string lpResult
            );

            [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
            private static extern ENetUseError WNetCancelConnection2(
                string lpName,
                int dwFlags,
                bool fForce
            );

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            private class NETRESOURCE
            {
                public int dwScope = 0;
                // Resource Type - disk or printer
                public int dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
                public int dwDisplayType = 0;
                public int dwUsage = 0;
                // Local Name - name of local device (optional, not used here)
                public string lpLocalName = "";
                // Remote Name - full path to remote share
                public string lpRemoteName = "";
                public string lpComment = "";
                public string lpProvider = "";
            }
            #endregion

            public static string ConnectToRemote(string remoteUNC, string username, string password)
            {
                NETRESOURCE nr = new NETRESOURCE { lpRemoteName = remoteUNC };
                ENetUseError ret = WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, password, username, 0, null, null, null);
                return ret == ENetUseError.NoError ? null : ret.ToString();
            }

            public static string DisconnectRemote(string remoteUNC)
            {
                ENetUseError ret = WNetCancelConnection2(remoteUNC, CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE, false);
                if (ret == ENetUseError.NoError) return null;
                return ret == ENetUseError.NoError ? null : ret.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Generally I wrap that in a disposable class that tests for direct access first.

Comment: i am getting same error user name and password incorrect